# AWS-CodeDeploy internal error for lambda function deployment using AWS-Codepipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am in the middle of setting code pipeline using code deploy in AWS for deploying lambda a function. I have created an application in codedeploy and using this application I have created a deployment in codedeploy for my lambda function and it was in successful status. And using this codedeploy application, I have created an aws pipeline with **Source** stage containing the path of my code jar file in S3 bucket. And I have **Deploy** stage in the pipeline using codedeploy for which the input artifact is the output artifact from **Source** stage. Pipeline succeed with the **Source** stage but whenever it reached the **Deploy** stage, it failed and the pipeline showed **Internal Error** only - no more information. I am having hard time to find the actual reason of the failure. Could someone please help?

Comment: Sounds like an AWS support issue.

Comment: @dashmug I have posted the same issue in aws codedeploy forum and it is not answered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Actual reason what I got from aws forum : "Currently CodePipeline does not support this feature. The CodePipeline team have an open feature request to add support for CodeDeploy Lambda deployments, however we are not able to share any ETA on this."

[Link for an answer from AWS codepipeline forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270326&tstart=0)